# Using help file (.sh6) in a windows form application on Visual Studio in C#

Tags: c#, helpfile

I've been trying for the past two days to find a way to connect a help file that has a .sh6 extension which i made, with a windows form application that i wrote in c#. Does anyone know how to add this file in visual studio and trigger it by pressing F1?

I'm using the latest version of visual studio, and HelpMaker 7.4.4.0 to created the .sh6 file.

Comment: I would guess that ".sh6" is some kind of HelpMaker project file, its not a Windows or Visual Studio thing so has no meaning there.  For a Help file you would use HelpMaker to produce a .CHM file & connect that to your app.  You will need to consult the HelpMaker docs for instruction.

Comment: I can confirm the comment of Alex.